# Android Proguard - step by step

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'm trying for the first time to use ProGuard on my Android project.

I have a couple of questions:

1. For jar-files in the /libs folder, how should they be referenced in the `proguard-project.txt`?

   - `-injars  /libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar`
   - or
   - `-libraryjars  /libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar`
   - ?
2. Do I have to write something down in the  `proguard-project.txt` for libraries that are library projects in my workspace?
3. I get a lot or warnings like this:

->

```
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.util.Xml depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - xy.de] Warning: library class android.view.LayoutInflater depends on program class org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser
```

what's up with that? XmlPullParser is a part of the Android framework right? How can it be missing?

4..

```
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - bauen.de] Warning: there were 42 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - bauen.de]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - bauen.de]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - bauen.de]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-08-12 14:27:13 - bauen.de]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
```

Should I really set `-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers`?

5. Is there a certain order that the settings in the `proguard-project.txt` must be set?

Comment: You don't need to add any library references in the proguard.txt file. Those are handled automatically.

Comment: Yes you dont have a need it will automatically generate in 2.3.3 or above

Comment: simple add proguard.config=proguard.cfg in project.properties

Comment: Okay, I deleted the injars / libraryjars comments, theres still the same errors as in 2.

Answer (score 2):

One of your libraries contains copies of org.xmlpull.v1 classes, even though those are already present in the Android runtime. You should remove those classes from the libraries. The versions in the Android runtime would get precedence anyway.

Cfr. ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

Comment: How does one remove files from a third party .jar? And does telling proguard to just ignore these errors cause harm?

Comment: @Mafro34 A jar file is just a zip file, so you can easily remove files from it. Ignoring the errors probably works, if there aren't any real compatibility clashes, but it is not very clean.